# set width image gridview yii2

Tags: gridview, yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

i am trying to set width the image in grid view.

```
 [   'attribute' => 'iduser.photo',
            'headerOptions' => ['width' => '20px'],
            'format' => 'image',
            'value'=>  function($data) { return Html::img("avatar.jpg",['width'=>'100']); },
        ],
```

this is the model

```
public function getImageurl()
{
    return Yii::$app->request->BaseUrl.'/avatar.jpg';
}
```

but the src result

http://localhost/belajar4/web/%3Cimg%20src=%22avatar.jpg%22%20width=%22100 %22%20alt=%22%22%3E

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try format `raw` this way

```
    [   'attribute' => 'iduser.photo',
        'headerOptions' => ['width' => '20px'],
        'format' => 'raw',
        'value'=>  function($data) { return Html::img("avatar.jpg",['width'=>'100']); },
    ],
```